# how iphone app Battery Log works?

Tags: iphone

I did some research and found that there is a log in the /private/var/ in which we can get the battery log. But unfortunately the iphone apps doesn't have read access to that file.

So I was wondering how the "Battery Log" works? (Battery Log is a app in the app store. It can display the battery history usage)

Answer (score 1):

In the application description it says that the application only gathers data when it is launched (which makes sense given the restrictions apple puts on apps and - as you mention - the Battery log file is private).  The app description also states that the app only works on a relative basis and cant get exact voltage.  Beyond that it seems like some black magic.

Comment: Yes I see "It acquires battery data upon launch".Dose that mean "only gathers data when it is launched"? Sorry, I am not a English native speaker, so that sentence confuse me.

Comment: that sentence doesn't necessarily mean "only gathers data when it is launched" but apple does not allow background processes so the app can only run when it is launched.

Comment: But is it possible that there is other ways to get the battery data? I means ,like a readable log file which like I said in my first post, Or communicate with some system processes to get that data.